# Spark: Why does Python read input files twice but Scala doesn't when creating a DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark v1.5.2. I wrote a program in Python and I don't understand why it reads the input files twice.  The same program written in Scala only reads the input files once.

I use an accumulator to count the number of times that `map()` is called.  From the accumulator value, I infer the number of times the input file is read.
The input file contains 3 lines of text.

Python:

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def createTuple(record):  # used with map()
    global map_acc
    map_acc += 1
    return (record[0], record[1].strip())

sc         = SparkContext(appName='Spark test app')  # appName is shown in the YARN UI
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
map_acc    = sc.accumulator(0)
lines      = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
people_rdd = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(",")).map(createTuple) #.cache()
fieldNames = 'name age'
fields     = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in fieldNames.split()]
schema     = StructType(fields)
df         = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people_rdd, schema)
print 'record count DF:', df.count()
print 'map_acc:', map_acc.value
#people_rdd.unpersist()
```

```
$ spark-submit --master local[1] test.py 2> err
record count DF: 3
map_acc: 6             #####  why 6 instead of 3??
```

Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def createTuple(record:Array[String], map_acc: Accumulator[Int]) = { // used with map()
        map_acc += 1
        Row(record(0), record(1).trim)
    }
    val conf       = new SparkConf().setAppName("Scala Test App")
    val sc         = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val map_acc    = sc.accumulator(0)
    val lines      = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt")
    val people_rdd = lines.map(_.split(",")).map(createTuple(_, map_acc))
    val fieldNames = "name age"
    val schema     = StructType(
        fieldNames.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
    val df         = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people_rdd, schema)
    println("record count DF: " + df.count)
    println("map_acc: " + map_acc.value)
  }
}
```

```
$ spark-submit ---class SimpleApp --master local[1] test.jar 2> err
record count DF: 3
map_acc: 3
```

If I remove the comments from the Python program and cache the RDD, then the input files are not read twice.  However, I don't think I should have to cache the RDD, right?  In the Scala version I don't need to cache the RDD.

```
people_rdd = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(",")).map(createTuple).cache()
...
people_rdd.unpersist()
```

```
$ spark-submit --master local[1] test.py 2> err
record count DF: 3
map_acc: 3
```

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat examples/src/main/resources/people.txt
Michael, 29
Andy, 30
Justin, 19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because in 1.5 `createDataFrame` [eagerly validates provided schema on a few elements](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.2/python/pyspark/sql/context.py#L296):

```py
elif isinstance(schema, StructType):
    # take the first few rows to verify schema
    rows = rdd.take(10)
    for row in rows:
        _verify_type(row, schema)
```

In contrast current versions [validate schema for all elements but it is done lazily](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L520) and you wouldn't see the same behavior. For example this would fail instantaneously in 1.5:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

rdd = sc.parallelize([("foo", )])
schema  = StructType([StructField("foo", IntegerType(), False)])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

but 2.0 equivalent would fail when you try to evaluate `DataFrame`.

In general you shouldn't expect that Python and Scala code will behave the same way unless you strictly limit yourself to interactions with SQL API. PySpark:

- Implements almost all RDD methods natively so the same chain of transformations can result in a different DAG.
- Interactions with Java API may require an eager evaluation to provide type information for Java classes.